# Error estimate of a Chebyshev polynomial approximation.

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation-theory, chebyshev-polynomials

I am trying to approximate a function $f(x)$ on $[-1, 1]$ using Chebyshev's polynomial of the first kind.
$$ f(x) \approx \sum_{i=0}^N a_iT_i(x) $$

What is the error of this approximation? Is it the same as the interpolation error:
$$ |f(x) - P(x)| = \frac{1}{2^n(n+1)!} \text{max}_{[-1, 1]} |f^{(n+1)} ({\xi}) |$$

(Sorry if it's trivial but I am trying to speed through a ton of notes on the internet and it's really confusing).

Comment: You need to specify _how_ you obtain the values for $a_i$. There are different ways for different problems and they give different errors

Comment: That is the error bound for using Chebyshev.